# Deleting Video File in Android

Tags: android

I want to the delete the file after compression is done. I have used the code to delete the file. But when I check in the Gallery the video file is still there but it doesn't play shows error Media not Supported. Here is my code.

```
if (compressed) {
              snackbar = TSnackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout,"Video Compressed Successfully",TSnackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar.show();
                //Delete File from Location.
                File videoFile = new File(mediaFile.getPath());
                if(videoFile.exists())
                {
                    boolean del =  videoFile.delete();
                }

            }
```

This is mediaFile

```
 mediaFile = new File(path + "VID_" + timestamp + ".mp4");
```

This is the storage directory

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    appName);
```

Comment: what is value of `del` and why you do not check it?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski it didn't print anything

Comment: That means video file does not exist???Please check the path

Comment: @akhilRao I have added the storage directory and file name

Comment: @akhilRao I am using this to delete the file:  File videofiles=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    "Wyntr-Beta"+"/"+mediaFile);

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski  V/log_tag: deleted: true But still the file doesn't get deleted

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(mediafile.getPath()),null,null);
```